# GPS intermediate Driver not returning valid results

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, gps

I'm trying to get Lat and Long data from my Windows Mobile 6.5 device using the GPS Intermediate Driver with the following code:

```
Gps gps = new Gps();
gps.Open();

var pos = gps.GetPosition();

while (!pos.LatitudeValid && !pos.LongitudeValid)
    pos = gps.GetPosition();

gps.Close();
```

The problem is that I never break the loop!  I tried using Bing Maps in the exact same spot and I get instant results using the GPSID.

All I need is relative (as in within 100 meters) lat and long data.  I pulled the GPSID dll from the 6.5.3 DTK, so I believe that it is the most up to date.  All the code that accesses the GPS is listed above, so if I'm missing something, please let me know!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty typical for COM components, they cannot update their internal state until you pump the message loop.  Which doesn't happen, you're stuck in a loop.  Use a Timer instead.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was something like that.  Could you put a small example using Timers?

Comment: You don't know how to use a Timer?  Please step away from the keyboard.

Comment: lol, nope I don't know how to use timers :)  What I mean by "small example" was did you mean add a timer that polls the `gps.GetPosition();` or use the internal Timer of the GPS class by directly subscribe to the "OnLocationChange" event for the gps object.  Also, I wanted to know if you had any particular insite into approprate tick intervals (I normally go for 100 ms, but then again, I don't know what I'm talking about) I actually ended up doing the latter (event subscription), but running it on a separate thread then calling Join which fit in nicely w/o having to re-do any of the logic.